# Conditional distributions of uniformly distributed random orthonormal matrices

Tags: pr.probability, riemannian-geometry, probability-distributions, random-matrices, haar-measure

Let $U, U'\in R^{d\times k} (d>k)$ be two independent uniformly distributed random orthonormal matrices. In specific, let $S$ be the set of all $d\times k$ orthonormal matrices. Here 'uniform' is defined with respect to $S$, i.e., in the sense of Haar measure. Let $\mu$ be the uniform probability measure over $S$.

Let us consider a subset $S'$ of $S$. Given any fixed $\lambda < 1$, our goal is to find
$$
S^* = \arg\max_{S':\mu(S') = \lambda} \mathbf{E}_{U, U'}\{\|U^T U'\|_F^2 ~|~ U, U'\in S'\}.
$$
Here the F-norm denotes the Frobenius norm, which is the square root of the sum of squares of all entries.

Question: what explicit form does such a maximizer $S^*$ take?

The most simplified case is $k=1$, where $S$ is the unit sphere and $S^*$ is the spherical cap. However, for general $k > 1$, it remains unclear what $S^*$ is like.

Comment: Please approve if the following interpetation of your qoustion is right.
You fix $0<\lambda<1$ and consider the collection $X$ consisting of subsets of $S$ of measure $\lambda$. You consider the function on $X$ given by $T \mapsto \int_{T\times T}\|U^tV\|^2 d\mu\times \mu(U,V)$ and ask for a discription of those $T$ on which it attains its maximum value.

Comment: and you do the above with respect to some norm on the space of $d\times d$-matrices (or is it $k\times k$?) which you denote by $F$ and leave its definition to our wild imagination.

Comment: @UriBader Yes your interpretation is exactly correct. Here I mean the Frobenius norm, i.e., the square root of the sum of squares of all entries of the matrix.

Comment: @UriBader Thanks for the clarification. I have edited the question accordingly. Please feel free to edit the question.